# Chrome: This site uses a plugin (Silverlight) that will soon be unsupported

Tags: google-chrome, silverlight, sharepoint-2010

I have a client with a SharePoint public website. In Chrome the users get a notified "This site uses a plugin (Silverlight) that will soon be unsupported". 
The site have no mediawebdel. 
Does anyone have tips to solve the problem with silverlight in chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Not much really you can do. Google is dropping support for NPAPI plugins which includes silverlight. You can read their timeline here

https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation

Answer (score 0):

We found cause for Silverlight message. We had a content query Web Part on the page and there it was ticked for it to play media links in the browser. When we removed this so we did not silverlight error on the page.:)